# How to stop the scrolling effect with jQuery slideToggle()

Tags: html, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I have some issues to stop the scrolling effect. For context, I use this code for hide and show some section on button click.

This is my code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.rv_button1').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#reveal1").slideToggle();
        $('.rv_button1').toggleClass('opened closed');
    });
});
```

I use wordpress with divi theme, the html is not really clear but this part is where my jQuery function is made for (sorry for my English though)

```
<div class="et_pb_button_module_wrapper et_pb_button_0_wrapper et_pb_button_alignment_center et_pb_module ">
    <a class="et_pb_button et_pb_button_0 rv_button et_pb_bg_layout_light opened" href="http://valerieb30.sg-host.com/notre-equipe/#reveal">Québec</a>
</div>
            
<div id="reveal" class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_1 et_pb_equal_columns et_pb_gutters2" style="display: block;">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_1  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
        <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_0  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
            <div class="et_pb_text_inner"><h2>Cuisinistes</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_de_mach_archive_loop et_pb_de_mach_archive_loop_0 main-loop loadmore-align- grid-layout-grid main-archive-loop
```

Comment: Post your HTML too please. We need a [mcve]

Comment: i edit my post with the html part thank you!